# Convert date time string with non standard timezone offset in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I couldn't find a .NET date format type to handle dates in format I need to process, they sometimes have time zone offset with +/- prefix followed by 3 digits for the number of minutes timezone is offset by. i.e. +11:00 is written as +660

Usage Example:

```
GetDateTime("20161124181215.000000+660")
```

The function:

```
private DateTime GetDateTime(string input)
    {
        int timezoneIndex = input.IndexOf('+');
        if (timezoneIndex < 0) { timezoneIndex = input.IndexOf("-"); }

        if (timezoneIndex >= 0)
        {
            string utcTime = input.Substring(0, timezoneIndex - 1);
            string timezoneOperator = input.Substring(timezoneIndex, 1);
            string timezoneOffset = string.Format(
                    "{0}{1}",
                    timezoneOperator,
                    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(input.Substring(timezoneIndex + 1))).ToString("hh\\:mm"));

            return DateTime.ParseExact(
                string.Format("{0}{1}", utcTime, timezoneOffset),
                "yyyyMMddHHmmss.FFFFFFK",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        else
        {
            return DateTime.ParseExact(
                input,
                "yyyyMMddHHmmss.FFFFFF",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }
```

Comment: [DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx)? Represents a point in time, typically expressed as a date and time of day, relative to Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Comment: @t3chb0t Except that all the .NET API's require time-zone formatting to be `HHmm`, not total minutes.

Comment: In addition to a code review, don't forget that this is the type of thing that needs *extensive* unit tests! There are plenty of subtle bugs potentially lurking here that even the most experienced programmer cannot be expected to catch by inspection alone.